# How to fasten rotating pieces without self-tightening (or loosening)?

Tags: metal, bolts, fastener, fastening

How does one fasten a rotating joint that does not self-tighten or self-loosen?

I'm trying to make a "slider crank" mechanism (for cheap) where all the movement is parallel to the ground. There are no huge forces at play, hoping to push a slider of a couple hundred grams ~15cm/6". Not my diagram, but essentially this:

[image: slider crank mechanism]

There are plenty of photos online, but I'm unclear how to robustly make joints (looks like they're labeled B and C in the diagram above). I've tried something like this:

[image: bolt with washers and nut]

but with the continuous rotation the nut eventually loosens or tightens.

Accepting that any pieces of hardware-store materials can be modified to suit, what is a good way to fasten these joints?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with home improvement.

Comment: @DanielGriscom this is a project for installation in my home where the central concern is common fasteners. Do you feel this is more appropriate on a different StackExchange?

Comment: @DanielGriscom -- would this be a good candidate for migrating to Engineering.SE?

Comment: I was just notified that this question received the "Popular Question" badge, so closing this without moving it to a more appropriate home seems like over-moderation. Perhaps more meta feedback, but closing well formed, answerable questions as off topic without an "on topic" SE feels destructive, where the upside is extremely subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bolt/nut configuration you show requires high friction against the joined members to maintain tightness.

You need independent locking of the nut. The most common method is to use *two* nuts. They are tightened against each other, rather than the captured articulating part.

An alternative is to use a nut locking compound (a sort of *nut glue*), and not fully tightening the nut, but the removable type will probably also eventually loosen, and the permanent type prevents easy disassembly.

I would also add a washer between the articulating arms or rotating parts.

Comment: Two nuts is the way to go. Other solutions will be more prone to loosening over time

Comment: Can you clarify where the two nuts would go? Exactly the same as the picture but with a second nut on the outside of the existing nut?

Comment: Yes. The inner nut is not quite tight against the washer, and is held with a wrench as the outer nut is tightened against it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to drill the hole to a larger diameter than the bolt and insert a metal sleeve that is slightly longer than the thickness of the 2 arms and tighten against the sleeve.  This will act as a replaceable bushing and should reduce wear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a bolt and nut design, just a short length of your aluminum rod with holes drilled for cotter pins, and washers.

Or a bolt and a castle nut with a hole drilled in the bolt for a cotter pin.